# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' (ubuntu)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ubuntu-20.04

Am a new user on `ubuntu version 20.04`.

The fresh install comes with python `3.8`, so i upgrade to latest `3.11`.

I do the usual `pip install pandas`.
Note i also try `pip3 install` pandas for good measure.

create a test file (called `test_pandas.py`) which contains this:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,6,8]}
df = pd.Dataframe(d)
print(df)
```

run file with:

```
python test_pandas.py
```

get this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

so i run file with this (the for 3.8 version python):

```
python3 test_pandas.py
```

and get this:

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

I have looked in several places (finally this: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), but all fail.

totally lost as what to do.
just want `3.11` (latest version) with a corresponding working pip.

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: it's `DataFrame`.

Comment: typo solves 50% (so, thanks for that correction).   so this tells me that pip is active on `python3.8`.  How to get pip active on `python3.11` ?

Comment: Did you try `python3.11 -m pip install pandas` ?

Comment: this works.   i thought that `python 3.11` was linked to python because when i run the command `python test_pandas.py` it works....  how to get them inline (for a new ubuntu user) ?

Comment: Glad it worked. For specific version of Python and pip, you can try what's here: https://river.me/blog/change-pip-version/

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around, I noticed other Stack posts are suggesting you install `wheel` and then `pandas`. You could try that.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean ? is that `pip install wheel` or `python3.11 -m pip install wheel` or something else ?

Comment: yes `pip install wheel`